# Sed to operate on line index based matching pattern and do operations

Tags: linux, sed

How `sed` is working on line match and occurrence based match patterns like below, where deleting or replacing a particular line ..

Below are some test, i could not understand why it only works on first matched and not on second.

**Initial 10 line of the log file:**

```
$ head smbd.log.old
[2020/02/16 03:53:55.112796,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 52391 -- ignoring
[2020/02/16 04:08:55.126564,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 52891 -- ignoring
[2020/02/16 04:23:55.209096,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 53648 -- ignoring
[2020/02/16 04:38:55.301910,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 54165 -- ignoring
[2020/02/16 04:53:55.382553,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 54920 -- ignoring
```

**Changing the first matched string to "Change_to_new":**

```
$ sed  '0,/2020/s//Change_to_new /' smbd.log.old | head
[Change_to_new /02/16 03:53:55.112796,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 52391 -- ignoring
[2020/02/16 04:08:55.126564,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 52891 -- ignoring
[2020/02/16 04:23:55.209096,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 53648 -- ignoring
[2020/02/16 04:38:55.301910,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 54165 -- ignoring
[2020/02/16 04:53:55.382553,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 54920 -- ignoring
```

**deleting the First match string:**

```
$ sed  '0,/2020/{//d;}' smbd.log.old | head
  Could not find child 52391 -- ignoring
[2020/02/16 04:08:55.126564,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 52891 -- ignoring
[2020/02/16 04:23:55.209096,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 53648 -- ignoring
[2020/02/16 04:38:55.301910,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 54165 -- ignoring
[2020/02/16 04:53:55.382553,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 54920 -- ignoring
[2020/02/16 05:08:55.427916,  2] ../source3/smbd/server.c:576(remove_child_pid)
```

**Why it did not work for Second match.**

```
$ sed  '1,/2020/{//d;}' smbd.log.old | head
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line address `0` is special. From [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-GNU-extensions_002c-0-address):

> 0,/regexp/
>
> A line number of 0 can be used in an address specification like 0,/regexp/ so that sed **will try to match regexp** in the first input
> line too.....

Because `sed` uses `/regexp/` on the first line of input in `0,/regexp/`, the `0,/regexp/{//d}` works fine. But `1,/regexp/{//d}` does not work, because `regexp` is unused on first line, so there were no previous matches.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think the picture is not complete without including this quote from the manual: `The empty regular expression "//" repeats the last regular expression match (the same holds if the empty regular expression is passed to the s command).` From: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses